# datebyAddingTimeInterval not working

Tags: ios, nsdate

in some cases, I need to increment a NSDate in 1 day. For it, I'm using dateByAddingTimeInterval, but it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *startDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/2012 %@",dayString, begin];
NSString *endStringForDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/2012 %@",dayString, end];

NSLog(@"Csantos: event starts: %@, event ends: %@", startDate, endStringForDate);

NSDate *beginDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:startDate];
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:endStringForDate];

NSComparisonResult result = [beginDate compare:endDate];


if(result == NSOrderedDescending){
    NSTimeInterval dayinseconds = 24 * 60 * 60;

    [endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:dayinseconds];
    NSLog(@"Csantos: event ends: %@", endDate);
}
```

Results:

```
2012-01-24 12:09:47.837 app[3689:207] Csantos: event starts: 19/02/2012 23:00, event ends: 19/02/2012 03:00
2012-01-24 12:09:47.837 app[3689:207] Csantos: event ends: 19/02/2012 03:00
```

I already tried addTimeInterval (deprecated, I know), but it's not working too. What is wrong?

Regards!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:dayinseconds];` returns a value which is the new date produced by the function. Dates are immutable objects (like strings) so you cannot modify them - you can only get a new date by applying a function.

If you write this, instead, it will work:

```
endDate = [endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:dayinseconds];
```

Comment: This would be date30 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(86400*30)];  Not plus 30 days.  This assumes now = today

Comment: @atilla You're right, there is more than one misconception in the original question, and I only addressed one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`[endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:dayinseconds];` doesn't change your existing object (endDate), it returns a new NSDate object, so do

```
endDate = [endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:dayinseconds];
NSLog(@"Csantos: event ends: %@", endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 4**, use [addingTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1408823-addingtimeinterval) method.

```
endDate = endDate.addingTimeInterval(dayinseconds)
```